# Spring RSocket not retrieving Mono response

Tags: java, dart, spring-webflux, rsocket

I am trying to make server request to clients using Rsocket(request-response pattern). On server I'm using Spring and my client is Dart([dart-rsocket](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-dart)). Debugging shows that server does receive data but I am unable to retrieve Mono(payload) from response.

On Server :

```
rsocketRequester.route(null).data("this is server reqeust!")
    .retrieveMono(String.class)
    .subscribe((value) -> {
        // Expectation : print payload data to console
        // Actual : No output on console
        System.out.println(value);
    });
```

have tried with `route("")` but no luck.

On Client:

```
List<int> list = 'this is client response!'.codeUnits;
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);

RSocketConnector connector = RSocketConnector.create().acceptor(requestResponseAcceptor((payload) {
    print(convertor(payload!.data!)); // to print server request payload
    return Future.value(Payload.from(null,bytes)); // Payload.from(metadata,data)
}));

var rsocket = await connector.connect("ws://localhost:7000/rsocket");
```

Server Debug :

[image]

Client side :

[image]

client receives request successfully. And server receives COMPLETE type frame with payload but nothing is printed on console.

Comment: I tried testing this with java client. And it worked as expected. One difference though, I received NEXT_COMPLETE frame instead of COMPLETE. Not sure if reactor library processes payload for COMPLETE frame or not, I will try to check.

Comment: roscket* library